# Three.js: mapping two textures to a cube

Tags: three.js

It's tough to find an updated answer to this question. Seems like a lot of solutions are using `MeshFaceMaterial` which is long gone from three.js (around version 53, currently on 84)

From the research I've done, it seems like it's a better strategy to create a Box, turn it into a Sphere and then do the mappings.

Here's what I've got:

I have textures loaded at vars `t1` and `t2`

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);

for (var i in geometry.vertices) {
    var vertex = geometry.vertices[i];
    vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar(1);
}

var mat1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: t1 });
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ map: t2 });

var materials = [mat1, mat2];
var mats = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);

var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, mats);

scene.add(cube);
```

Problems:

- This is resulting in `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'visible' of undefined` in my console
- For shading reasons, I'd like to use a MeshPhongMaterial instead of a MeshLambertMaterial

Any tips would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `materialIndex` value inside the faces of the geometry. These values are indexes into your `materials` array.

In your example you will see they have values from `0` to `5` (corresponding to sides of the box), but since only two materials are provided then you'll see an error.

To solve your problem you can just change the `materialIndex` values on the geometry faces so that they just reference your two materials.

For example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 1) {
  var face = geometry.faces[i];
  face.materialIndex = face.materialIndex % 2;
}
```